# Правильно ли написан код?

Tags: java

```
class My Class 
{
   int a; 
   int b;

   MyClass (int i, int j)
   {
        a = i;
        b = j;
   }
   MyClass (int i)
   {
       this(i, i);
   }
   MyClass ()
   {
       this(0)
   }
}
```

**ВОПРОС:**

Почему в конструкторе `this(i,i)` a не `this(i,j)`?

```
MyClass (int i)
{
   this(i,i);
}
```

Comment: В этом конструкторе переменная i не определена. Код просто не скомпилируется (если это не опечатка)

Comment: Во втором конструкторе не указано имя переменной, только тип.

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что класс содержит два поля `a` и `b`. Судя по всему, при создании экземпляра класса оба этих поля необходимо инициализировать. При этом, данная конкретная перегрузка конструктора класса принимает только один параметр. Значение этого параметра и используется для инициализации обоих полей. То есть:

```
MyClass m =  new MyClass(5);
```

Это тоже самое, что:

```
MyClass m =  new MyClass(5,5);
```

И в том и в другом случае поле `a` и поле `b` будут равны числу `5`.

Comment: А разве такое прокатит `new MyClass(5);`? У ТС написан конструктор `MyClass(int)` =)  если он не опечатался, конечно же, в чем я лично сомневаюсь)

Comment: А для чего тогда j в конструкторе? Почему конструктор this не переопределяет (i, j)? именно (i,i)? Я ваш ответ понимаю, но меня смущает почему не (i, j), ведь именно этот конструктор переопределяют MyClass(int i, int j) { a=i; b=j; Я понимаю,что у нас есть а и b, но ведь b=j, а не i! Спасибо!

Comment: ИМХО, скорее всего это действительно опечатка. В противном случае, будет ошибка компиляции.

Comment: То есть, я права? не заблуждаюсь? Пример из Шилдта

Comment: Да, там действительно опечатка. Нужно дописать MyClass(int i).

Comment: Да-к тут и так есть  MyClass (int i), где именно прописать  MyClass (int i)?